# Is it bad practise to save calculated data into a db as opposed to inputs for the calculation? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Is it bad practise to save calculated data into a database record, as opposed to just inputs for the calculation?

**Example:**

If we're saving results of language tests as a db record, and the test has 3 parts which need to be saved in separate columns: `listening_score`, `speaking_score`,`writing_score`

Is it ok to have a forth column called `overall_score`, equal to
`( listening_score + speaking_score + writing_score ) / 3`?

Or should `overall_score` be recalculated each time `current_user` wants to look at historical results.

My thinking is that this would cause unnecessary duplication for data in the db. But it would make make extracting data simpler.

Is there a general rule for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not bad, but it's not good. There's no best practice here, because the answer is different in each situation. There are trade offs for persisting the calculated attributes instead of calculating them as needed. The big factors in deciding on whether to calculate when needed or persist are:

1. Complexity of calculation
2. Frequency of changes to dependent fields
3. Calculated field to be used a search criteria
4. Volume of calculated data
5. Usage of calculated fields (eg: operational/viewing one record at a time vs. big data style reporting)
6. Impact to other processes during calculation
7. Frequency that calculated fields will be viewed.

There are a lot of opinions on this matter. Each situation is different. you have to determine whether the overhead of persisting your attributes and maintaining their values is worth the extra effort than just calculating it as needed.

Using the factors above, my preference for persisting a calculated attribute increases as

- Complexity of calculation goes up
- Frequency of changes to dependent fields goes down
- Calculated field to be used a search criteria goes up
- calculated field are used for complicated reporting
- Frequency that calculated fields will be viewed goes up.

The factors I omitted from the second list are dependent on external factors, and are subject to even more variability.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the calculated total could be thought of as caching. Caching calculations like this means you have to start dealing with keeping the calculation up to date and worrying about when it isn't. In the long run, that pattern can result in a lot of work. On the flip side, always calculating the total means you will always have a fresh calculation to work with.

I've seen folks store calculations to address performance issues, when calculating is taking a long time due to its complexity or the complexity of the query its based off of. That's a good reason to start thinking about caching results like this.

I've also seen folks store this value to make queries easier. That's a lower return on investment, but can still be worth it if the columns used in your calculations aren't changing frequently.

My default is to calculate, and I want to see good justification for storing the value of the calculation in another column.

(It may also be worth noting that if you are using the same calculation multiple times in a particular function call, you can memoize the result to increase performance without storing the result in the database.)

Comment: problem is its kinda hard to sort the `activerecords` based on calculated columns, any thoughts or words for that?

Comment: @buncis agreed. It can also be slow. You could make it easier by writing a SQL view, but if you want fast + easy you need to store it somehow.